# Horizontally concatenating the entries of two matrices, and padding with NaNs

Tags: performance, matrix, matlab, vectorization

I have two matrices `a` and `b` that have, on each line, some values (null or not) and then a bunch of zeros at the end.

I want to construct a matrix `c` that for each line has the corresponding line of `a` from the first element till to the last not-null element, concatenated with the corresponding line of `b` from the first element till to the last not-null element. Like in the following example:

```
>> a=[1 NaN 3 0; 1 0 0 0]

a =

     1   NaN     3     0
     1     0     0     0

>> b=[1 0 1 0; 0 0 0 0]

b =

     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0

>> c=NaN(2,8) %same dimension as a and b   

c =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

        for ii=1:size(a,1)
        [v,x]=find(a(ii,:));
        if numel(x)>0 %it could be all null
            x1=a(ii,1:x(end)); %x(end) because I want to retain the zeros before the last not-null element
        end
        [v,x]=find(b(ii,:));
        if numel(x)>0
            x1=[x1 b(ii,1:x(end))];
        end
        c(ii,1:numel(x1))=x1;
        end
>> c

c =

     1   NaN     3     1     0     1   NaN   NaN
     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

How can I improve this code?
`a` and `b` always have the same dimensions (that can be different from the example though). `a` and `b` values can be positive/negative finite or infinite doubles or NaNs.
In my case I am interested only to merge two matrices.

Are there "standard" ways to vectorize a code? What do you look at when thinking to how vectorize a code?

Comment: Out of curiosity — what do `a` and `b` represent, and why do you want to do this operation?

Comment: @200_success It comes out during a messy data post-processing. I have a matrix of the dimensions of `c` containing an index that determines what I have to do with the values in a matrix A with the same dimensions.  Unfortunately A got split in`a` and `b` during the data analysis. The fastest solution is now to merge them again. The data are temperature and stratification data of ocean water columns.

Comment: @StewieGriffin unfortunately I think that the only thing that it cannot be is `-Inf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two major way to simplify and speed this up.  First, rather than copying `a` to `c` at every step of the loop, you can define `c` to include `a` from the beginning.  Second, you can find all the nonzero, non-NaN values in a vectorized manner at the very beginning  This reduces the time for me be about 1/2 for a large (~10000 row) random data set.

```
function c = catnonzero_2(a, b)
    c=[a, NaN(size(b))];
    agood = a~=0;
    bgood = b~=0;
    for ii=1:size(a,1)
        ailast=find(agood(ii,:), 1, 'last');
        if isempty(ailast)
            ailast = 0;
        end
        bilast=find(bgood(ii,:), 1, 'last');
        if ~isempty(bilast)
            c(ii, ailast+1:ailast+bilast) = b(ii, 1:bilast);
        else
            c(ii, ailast+1:end) = NaN;
        end
    end
end
```

This can be improved even more by separating out the rows that can be vectorized from those that can't.

1. I find all the rows of `a` and `b` with some non-null values ("good" rows).  Rows that aren't good are then filled with `NaN`.
2. I find all the rows of `a` and `b` where the last value is non-null ("perfect" rows).
3. For rows that are good but not perfect ("imperfect" rows):

   1. For `b` I can loop over them an put the `NaN` values at the end.  This allows me to treat all `b` rows as either "perfect" or "bad", since the "imperfect" rows already have the `NaN` values at the end and thus can be used in the entirety.
   2. For `a`, I can loop over the rows where `a` are imperfect and `b` are not good and put `NaN` at the end of those.  Where `b` is good, `b` will be ovewriting those anyway so it isn't necessary as long as `b` is at least as long as `a`.
4. I make `c` like in the previous example.
5. In cases where `a` is perfect and `b` is good, I can just write `b` to `c` at the point where `a` ends.
6. In the cases where `a` is bad and `b` is food, I can just write `b` from the start of `c`.
7. In the remaining cases, I have to calculate where `b` starts, and then write `b`.
  3.

This reduces the time for me by about another 1/4:

```
function c = catnonzero_3(a, b)
    alen = size(a, 2);
    blen = size(b, 2);

    agood = a~=0;
    bgood = b~=0;

    agoodrows = any(agood, 2);
    bgoodrows = any(bgood, 2);

    aperfectrows = agood(:,end);
    bperfectrows = bgood(:,end);
    aimperfectrows = agoodrows & ~aperfectrows;

    a(~agoodrows, :) = NaN;
    b(~bgoodrows, :) = NaN;

    if alen <= blen
       apadtarg = aimperfectrows & ~bgoodrows;
    else
       apadtarg = aimperfectrows;
    end

    for ii=find(apadtarg)'
        a(ii, ailast(ii)+1:end) = NaN;
    end
    for ii=find(bgoodrows & ~bperfectrows)'
        b(ii, bilast(ii)+1:end) = NaN;
    end

    c=[a, NaN(size(b))];

    ailast = @(ii) find(agood(ii,:), 1, 'last');
    bilast = @(ii) find(bgood(ii,:), 1, 'last');

    aperfbgood = aperfectrows & bgoodrows;
    c(aperfbgood, size(a, 2)+1:end) = b(aperfbgood, :);

    abadbgood = ~agoodrows & bgoodrows;
    c(abadbgood, 1:blen) = b(abadbgood, :);

    for ii=find(aimperfectrows & bgoodrows)'
        ajj = ailast(ii);
        c(ii, ajj+1:ajj+blen) = b(ii, :);
    end
end
```

And here is the data set I used to test (your version is `catnonzero_1`:

```
a=randi([-11, 10], 100000,80);
b=randi([-11, 10], 100000,100);

a(a==-11) = NaN;
b(b==-11) = NaN;

timeit(@() catnonzero_1(a, b))
timeit(@() catnonzero_2(a, b))
timeit(@() catnonzero_3(a, b))
```

And the result:

```
>> run_w_time

ans =

    0.889284394000000


ans =

    0.411362394000000


ans =

    0.102184394000000


ans =

    1


ans =

    1


c1 = catnonzero_1(a, b);
c2 = catnonzero_2(a, b);
c3 = catnonzero_3(a, b);

all(all(c1(~isnan(c1))==c2(~isnan(c2))))
all(all(c1(~isnan(c1))==c3(~isnan(c3))))
```

Comment: You had my upvote almost a month ago, but I just re-read the answer. I just want to say: This is a very good answer in my eyes =)